# NativeActivity fullscreen and navigation hidden without java code?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to have a true fullscreen android application using NativeActivity. I'm setting the theme "Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" in the AndroidManifest.xml but that only hides the titlebar and not the navigation. Looking here it can be done from java code:
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

But I'm looking for a way to do this from native code or by setting something in AndroidManifest.xml. Is there a way to do this? Otherwise I guess one have to inherit from the NativeActivity.java and do the java code but it would be nice to have a full native solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can have solution for this.

1) add in this code to style.xml

```
 <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

2) in manifests file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
       android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"></activity>
```

it will create fullscreen activity

**Edited**

use following style for full screen

```
 <style name="CodeFont" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
 </style>
```

we can also create full screen directly from manifest

```
<activity
 android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

Comment: styles.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'.

styles.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarStyle'.

styles.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.

maybe when you answer a question you can actually offer a solution that works...

Comment: check out edited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060992/nativeactivity-fullscreen-and-navigation-hidden-without-java-code/36061712#36061712